# Що таке "пів-тяги" в реченні "Від кашлю до кашлю минуло пів тяги, трамвай вже поїхав, іди власним ходом"?

Tags: значення-слів

Цитата з пісни Лея - [Прокинься](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-vg-A88Bak):

> Прокинься, будильник дзвенить вже хвилину
> вставай і біжи, доки вистачить сил.
> "Чого така втомлена й досі сонлива?" -
> лунають у вухах брудні голоси.

> Від кашлю до кашлю минуло **пів тяги**,
> трамвай вже поїхав, іди власним ходом,
> на стінах гойдаються атласні стяги,
> ніяк не пов’язані з рідним народом.

Мені здається, що **пів-тяги** означає "поки ти кашляла, трамвай встиг відійти від зупинки і розігнатися на половину своєї швидкості". Я правий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гадаю, що йдеться про пів затяжки димом з цигарки.

> **[ЗАТЯЖКА](https://sum.in.ua/s/zatjazhka)**, и, жін.
>
> 2. Втягування за одним вдихом тютюнового диму під час куріння. — *Хай спочине, чаю нап'ється, покуре [покурить], — думав Проценко. А Довбня, сидячи за столом, кадив, мов з димаря, на всю хату, запиваючи чаєм кожну затяжку* (Панас Мирний, III, 1954, 202); *Перед тим, як відповісти на будь-яке, навіть незначне питання, майор обов'язково робив дві затяжки із своєї невеличкої люльки, яка завжди стриміла під пожовтілими від тютюну вусами* (Вадим Собко, Запорука.., 1952, 85).